# Extracting a string from regular expression

Tags: regex

Using regular expressions, I want to extract the name2 from `name1_99_name2.sql`

- `name1` : any sequence of characters
- `99` : any sequence of numbers
- `name2` : any sequence of characters

Using this:

```
\_[a-z]+
```

I extract `name2` with the underscore before, but I need it without it.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. First of all, what language are you using? Second, what is a 'character'? I'm asking because a character can be _anything_ really, including a space, tab, newline, or even ✭ are characters.

Comment: The regular expression have following format:
[a-z|A-Z]+_+[0-9]+_+[a-z|A-Z]+\.+sql

I need to extract the second string using just regular expressions

Comment: But what engine are you using to run your regex?

Comment: It works with: [^_]+?(?=[.])

Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[^_]+(?=\.sql$)
```

If your string always ends with ".sql".

But as Hayk pointed out, maybe you don't really need a regex here as a simple string manipulation function could do the job.